# mysql how to get duplicate data from each UPDATE.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table with following field...

```
student_id, name, email, age
```

I use below code for update my student table data:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "student SET name = '" . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", email= '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . ", age= '" . $this->db->escape($data['age']) . " WHERE student_id = '" . (int)$student_id . "'");
```

My question is how can I get **DUPLICATE** field for when each updates? I mean when we update my table, the new data must be a duplicate table with new added data's, like copy of the previous data with updated....

*I am not much expert with mysql.*

Comment: So whenever you update a single row in a table, you want a copy of the old data to be preserved? You can do that with Triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: @Dai... what i want is, when update data my previous data no need to change, but updated data must be like a copy of previous data... so each updates a new data will be created

Comment: then you have insert data with duplicates not update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a data_versioning in my own CMS a couple of weeks ago. The idea was pretty simple. I use an extra database tabel `data_versioning` which has a couple of fields:

- dv_id
- dv_table
- dv_primary_key
- dv_data
- dv_created_by
- dv_created_at

dv_id is the primary key of the table, dv_created_by is a user_id and dv_created_at is a datetime field. These are the less important fields, the 3 importent fields are:

1. **dv_table**: this field contains the name of the database table, for instance `students`.
2. **dv_primary_key**: this field contains the primary key of the `students` table. To identify for what row the data_vesion on.
3. **dv_data**: contains a serialized string of the array of data that was previously in your row

The method I used is:

1. The edit page of a row first checked and fetched the data, storing it in a variable, for example: `$studentData = $db->fetch("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = 1");`
2. When a POST-request is found the fields in the POST are being checked (validation) just to make sure the new entry is valid for our database.
3. As soon as the entry is valid, the "magic" happens

The magic being:

1. Create a data_version to be inserted: `$db->query("INSERT INTO data_version (dv_table, dv_primary_key, dv_data) VALUES ('students', 1, '".serialize($studentData)."')");`
2. Then update the current row: `$db->update("UPDATE students SET ... WHERE id = 1");`
3. Update the $studentData array with the new data: `$studentData = $_POST;`

Part 3 is optional. In my case, after someone submits changes I update my table, display a success/error message and the edit-form is available again containing the new data. This edit for is populated with `$studentData`.. so this array has to be updated otherwise it contains the data of a previous entry (since $studentData is being populated at top of your page).

**Restoring data**

Restoring data would be as easy as getting a list with available versions from the table data_versions based on the dv_table and dv_primary_key fields. Then unserialize() the dv_data field and update the data. The dv_data field contains the table fields

The OO-integrations is a little bit different. You would in that case just put an extra before() function in your save handler to write to the data_version table.

I'm not sure if this is the best option. But in my case I was looking for a solution that only needed 1 database table instead of a `students_versions`, `news_versions` and so on.